# Gecko trouble shedding, helped to remove skin but dead ends look like toenails

Tags: leopard-geckos, shedding

My Leopard Gecko has had some trouble shedding and I’ve read all about the warm soaks and removing the skin from the toes. I’ve done all this but there are still bits on the end that look like toenails/dead skin. One looks like dried blood and is very long. I’m not sure if anyone else has had these issues? I’m not sure if I should try to take that part off as well or leave it. It’s been there for about a week and seems super sensitive. She doesn’t react well whenever I touch it.